# understanding example: a cone over natural numbers not homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to understand following example from Dugundji-Topology.

Let consider $X=\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\times \{0\}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $C(X)$ the cone over $X$, i.e. with $I=[0,1]$, 
$$C(X)=(X\times I)/(X\times \{1\}).$$

Let $Y$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ obtained by joining $w_0=(0,1)$ to each point of $X$.

**Claim:** The space $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic, although there is continuous bijection $X\rightarrow Y$.

**Proof.** For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ let $V_n$ denote the set of all point on the line segment joining $w_0$ to $(n,0)$ within $1/n$ of $w_0$ and $V=\cup_n V_n$. Then  $V$ is open in the cone $X$  but is not open in $Y$.

**Question.** Can one explain some points here with some hints if one want to post not full answer?

Especially, I do not understand following about $V_n$. What do we mean *within $1/n$ of $w_0$?* The second question, instead of taking $V_n$ if we take $W_n$ to be those point on the line segment joining $w_0$ to $(n,0)$ within fixed, say $1/2$ of $w_0$, then will the set  $\cup_n W_n$ distinguish topology of $X$ and $Y$?

For continuous bijection, is the following way correct?

From $X\times I$ to $Y$, obtain a surjective map which is constane only on $X\times \{1\}$ and injective on rest of the subset of $X\times I$. Then $f$ induces a required continuous bijection between $C(X)$ and $Y$.

Comment: If $L_n$ is the line segment from $w_0$ to $(n,0)$, so $L_n = \{((1-t)n, t): t \in [0,1]\}$, then $V_n = B(w_0, \frac{1}{n}) \cap L_n$ where $B(x,r)$ denotes the open ball in the Euclidean distance around $x$ with radius $r$.

Comment: The quotient $C(X)$ is not first countable at the $X \times \{1\}$ point. And $Y$ is first countable at each point, being metric.

Comment: The continuous map is just the union of all linear functions mapping $\{n\} \times [0,1]$ bijectively to $L_n$ mapping $(n,1)$ to $w_0$, factored through the quotient. This corresponds to your description I believe.

Comment: Sorry I know this is an old question, but can someone please explain to me why the sets $V_n$ are not open in the subspace topology n $\mathbb{R}^2$?